# How to fix 'class android::Surface' has no member named 'setDirtyRect'?

Tags: android, c++

While building Android (OmniRom, based on 5.1) I've got this:

```
target thumb C++: libandroid_runtime <= frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_InputQueue.cpp
frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_Surface.cpp: In function 'void android::nativeSetDirtyRect(JNIEnv*, jclass, jlong, jobject)':
frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_Surface.cpp:211:14: error: 'class android::Surface' has no member named 'setDirtyRect'
     surface->setDirtyRect(&rect);
              ^
target thumb C++: libandroid_runtime <= frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_KeyEvent.cpp
target thumb C++: libandroid_runtime <= frameworks/base/core/jni/android_view_KeyCharacterMap.cpp
make: *** [/home/ice552/omni/out/target/product/find7op/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libandroid_runtime_intermediates/android_view_Surface.o] Ошибка 1
make: *** Ожидание завершения заданий...
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/omni/general/help-regarding-compiling-omnirom-cm-t2964759/page2

Comment: @Dan https://www.dropbox.com/s/cia2teetpgtkai1/android_view_Surface.cpp?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Building 5.1 for CAF devices is not yet possible.

You also need to use branch android-5.1-caf for av and native repos

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply these two patches to frameworks/native: http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/62472/2 https://gerrit.omnirom.org/#/c/11061/1/

Recovery will also throw an error, so you need to add graphics from 5.0.